# How to make a single class which handles socket connection and communication for whole android app?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm using socket communication in my android app. Right now I'm opening socket for every message I send to server and then close it.
In my every `Activity` I have a private class which extends from `AsyncTask`.

Something like following code:

```
 public class MainWindowActivity extends Activity{

 ...

      private class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, String> {
           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {
               // opening socket

               // sending mesasge

               // closing socket

               return result;
           }
       }
  }
```

My question is that can I make a class for communication which open a socket when user does login and closes it when user does logout and I can use that socket instance in my all activities?

Comment: Don't know about socket but Service can be used for such a things...I have created MediaPlayer in Service class which can be used in any activity for playing music.

Comment: A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors). A NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. So i can't use service